# The cancel button can not show up when the search bar is title view of navigation bar

Tags: ipad, ios9, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I met a problem (It seems an Apple bug) when adding `UISearchController.searchBar` as `titleView` of `UINavigationItem` in `UISplitViewController`. The cancel button always can not show up even I called `searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;`.

This only happen when using `UISearchController` which is new in iOS 9 and running on iPad, it can not be reprod on iPhone 6+/6s+ landscape mode.

I have a demo here, how could I work around this problem? Here is the [sample code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/etu4k2hrxs9jasd/testSearchInNavBar.zip?dl=0) and screenshot:

[image: screenshot of no cancel button]

Comment: did you ever end up figuring this out?

Comment: No, I haven't, still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I ended up adding the UISearchBar but "swapping" the right UIBarButtonItem for a cancel button